# 1989 s10 blazer loss of power on slopes

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, power-loss

Lately ever since winter began , Ive been having some loss of power going up slopes in my 89 blazer. I live in Calgary Alberta, and going west on stony trail from Deerfoot seems to be an issue.The moment i hit a slope my speed keeps dropping from 100 to 60. This used to happen during summer. During that time i used to downshift and that helped keep up the pace. When i downshift in winter i can hear the engine rev but there is still a delay in power getting to the rear wheels. At times i have to have the pedal to the ground to get some kind of speed. I have winter tires on .

Could someone give me some insight as to what could be the cause? What should i do to began testing.?

**Vehicle spec**
Engine:4.3 L TBI V6 engine
Transmission : 4 speed Automatic with Overdrive (4th gear is OD)
Mileage: 180200 KM
Parts Changed:
 distributor cap ,rotor and coil. new spark plugs

The previous owner stated that he did some work around the engine, didn't mention anything about rebuilding it.

*Stony Trail is a highway in calgary , the section im talking about in the post has a lot of slopes.
Deerfoot is just an another highway.*

Comment: When the power loss occurs, is the engine RPM  increasing when you press the accelerator pedal?

Comment: It struggles at times,sometimes I have to slam the pedal down to get some response.

Comment: There are some key details missing. 1) We are not familiar with Stony Trail. What is the grade? If it is very steep, it will cause the truck to slow down naturally. 2) How is the truck loaded? Is it full of bricks, wood, etc. or is it empty? A load is going to have an effect on its ability to climb hills. 3) What is the condition of the engine? Has it been serviced regularly? What is the mileage? All these details are important for anyone to attempt to help you over the Internet.

Comment: Stony Trail is a highway in calgary , the section im talking about in the post has a lot of slopes. Deerfoot is just an another highway. 2. The truck is empty. I got the engine when it had `162000 km on the clock, as of now i changed the distributor cap ,rotor and coil. new spark plugs and did an oil change to synthetic oil.

Answer (score 1):

If your vehicle has a manual trasmission, its possible that your clutch is going out. If the revs are going up when you hit the gas but you don't feel the power getting to the tires, then its probably the clutch. Here is a video that shows you a few tricks on how to diagnose a bad clutch

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7JJ_g2UuBI

Another trick not mentioned in the video is to downshift one gear while driving without hitting the gas, if downshifting does not make your rpms jump significantly then it means that the clutch is slipping and needs to be replaced

Comment: I downshifted to d from overdrive and the RPM jumped . felt the car buckle down due to torque. Does this rule out the clutch ?

Comment: Sounds like this is an automatic transmission. Is that correct @AllanVarkey?

Comment: Judging by the OP's input, this vehicle has an auto transmission, making this answer non-applicable to the question.

Comment: yeah if you have an automatic transmission then my answer doesn't apply. I assumed from the sentence "During that time i used to downshift and that helped keep up the pace. When i downshift in winter i can hear the engine rev but there is still a delay in power getting to the rear wheels." but I should have confirmed whether it was automatic or manual first

Comment: should I delete the answer then since it doesn't apply?

Comment: I guess if you edit and say its for manual transmission, it might help someone who has a manual transmission

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes it is automatic. i should have been more clear on the post. sorry.